# Capture past terminal messages / session text

Tags: linux, terminal

Is it possible to capture all messages from current terminal session and write them to a file ?

- I don't mean capturing command output or monitor any further messages using >>, script or tee.
- What I mean is literally dumping to a file what is already on screen
- I totally dont mean selecting anything by mouse and copying to clipboard

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the contents of virtual consoles using `setterm`'s `-append` or `-dump` flags and the TTY #:

```
setterm -append 3
```

will append contents from the VCS TTY 3 to the file `screen.dump`.

Otherwise, you may need to use something like `screen`, which allows you to dump what's in the scrollback buffer to a file.